# Bind selected value from ASP.NET DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, bind

When I bind the value of a TextBox in the .aspx page, I do the following inside a ListView:

`<asp:TextBox ID="NameTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>' />`

How can I bind the value from a DropDownList the same way?

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="TestDropDownList" runat="server">
   <asp:ListItem Value="Test 1">Test 1</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem Value="Test 2">Test 2</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Answer (score 3):

To bind to a DropDownList, you would bind your datasource to the DropDownList control, and specify your Text and Value at that stage like:

```
cmd SqlCommand = new SqlCommand("Your SQL Command Here", conn);

TestDropDownList.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
TestDropDownList.DataTextField = "Name";
TestDropDownList.DataValueField = "Value";
TestDropDownList.DataBind();
```

This is the equivalent of you trying to do something like this:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="TestDropDownList" runat="server">
   <asp:ListItem Value="<%# Bind("Value") %>"><%# Bind("Name") %></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: I don't get how to add the DataSource from code-behind? Also how do I add multiple ListItems this way?

Comment: @user1121487 - See edit, I've included more on how to make a DataSource